# Non relative paths in javadoc images?

Tags: java, image, javadoc

Default recommendation is to put image files into `doc-files` subdirectory of package directory and refer them with relative `IMG` tag.

But this means image can be used for one class only. If the same image should be used for many classes or if class is moved to another package, links become invalid.

Is it possible to put images somewhere into package independent place and refer them portable?

Comment: What prevents you from using a relative path to an image stored in another package?

Comment: It will still depend on current package